# Given a compact space $T^*$ and Hausdorff space $T$ on set $X$ such that $T^* \subseteq T$. Show that $T^*=T$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(X,T)$ be a compact topological space. Let $T^*$ be a topology on $X$ such that $T^*$ is contained in $T$ and suppose that $(X,T^*)$ is  Hausdorff space. Show that $T^*=T$

To prove $T^*=T$, I have to show that $T^*$ is contained in $T$ and vice versa. It is already given that $T^*$ is contained in $T$. I just have to show that "$T$ is also contained in $T^*$". How do I do it? Can anyone help?

Comment: You mixed up the topologies: the compact one has to be the finer one, the T2 the coarser one. Then they are equal, but, of course, not vice versa. The statement and proof of Ero Sennin is correct, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it directly with open covers.

Suppose that $\mathscr{T}^*\subsetneqq\mathscr{T}$, and let $U\in\mathscr{T}\setminus\mathscr{T}^*$. Let $K=X\setminus U$; $K$ is not closed in $\langle X,\mathscr{T}^*\rangle$, but $K$ **is** closed in $\langle X,\mathscr{T}\rangle$, which is a compact space, so $K$ is compact in $\langle X,\mathscr{T}\rangle$.

Let $\mathscr{V}$ be a cover of $K$ by $\mathscr{T}^*$-open sets. $\mathscr{T}^*\subseteq\mathscr{T}$, so $\mathscr{V}$ is automatically also a $\mathscr{T}$-open cover of $K$, and as such it has a finite subcover $\mathscr{V}_0$. Thus, every cover of $K$ by $\mathscr{T}^*$-open sets has a finite subcover, and $K$ is therefore compact in $\langle X,\mathscr{T}^*\rangle$. But every compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed, and $\langle X,\mathscr{T}^*\rangle$ is Hausdorff, so $K$ is closed in $\langle X,\mathscr{T}^*\rangle$. This contradiction shows that $\mathscr{T}$ cannot be a proper subset of $\mathscr{U}$.